# How to prevent paper-dropdown-menu from changing hight of its list?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have simple `paper-dropdown-menu`:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="select">
     <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
          <paper-item>option a</paper-item>
          <paper-item>option b</paper-item>
     </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

When I click the dropdown for the first time everything is ok, but each next click cuts height of the list in half (in Dartium):

[image]

It works well when I compile this to `javascript`:

[image]

How to prevent this behaviour in Dartium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Dartium, it should work fine in other browsers. A new version of Dartium was announced for Dart 1.14.